# List index out of range How to fix

Tags: python, pycharm, range

I have A problem that says List index out of range

How to fix?

```py
combo_list=[]
_combo_ = open("combo.txt", "r").readlines()
_combo_new = [items.rstrip() for items in _combo_]
for lines in _combo_new:
    new_lines = lines.split(":")
    combo_list.append({"username": new_lines[0],
                            "password": new_lines[1]})
    print(combo_list)
```

Here is the "combo.txt"
its on this form email:pass

```
[{'username': 'kazut@app-expert.com', 'password': 'kazut@app-expert.com'}
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/test6.py", line 7, in <module>
    "password": new_lines[1]})
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I suspect the `new_lines[1]` is the guilty. Check the length of `new_lines` before `new_lines[1]`. You can get the length with [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

Comment: are there any empty lines in the file, or lines without a ":"?

Comment: It would be better if you had saved the file in actual JSON format, then you could just do `json.loads()` instead of parsing it manually.

Comment: I ran the code with that data and no errors were raised,

Comment: ya its weird its working on other computers and not on mine

Answer (score 0):

If you `split(':')` in this line `[{'username': 'kazut@app-expert.com', 'password': 'kazut@app-expert.com'}` the result will be a list with the following values:

1. `"[{'username'"`
2. `"'kazut@app-expert.com', 'password'"`
3. `"'kazut@app-expert.com'}"`

if you don't want to parse your data to `json` it's safer to `split('\'')` like this:

```
combo_list=[]
_combo_ = open("a.txt", "r").readlines()
_combo_new = [items.rstrip() for items in _combo_]
for lines in _combo_new:
    new_lines = lines.split("\'")
    combo_list.append({"username": new_lines[3],
                            "password": new_lines[7]})
    print(combo_list)
```

Comment: combo .txt  is on the format   email:pass not [{'username': 'email', 'password': 'password'}